# Networking joining 2 networks togeather

Tags: router

Have Shed(192.168.1.1) router handling my DHCP and has the WAN connection to the NET.
then I have connect the Home (192.168.1.2)router with DHCP turned off.
I also CCTV(192.168.0.1) router connected to the Shed router via the wan port(LAN to WAN) (192.168.1.30)
I want CCTV to issue DHCP for the ESP32CAM devices!
Looking at how to make the CCTV router Issue DCHP and be able to bridge back to the Shed Router and be seen across the internal network. The ESP32 device do appear to handle VLAN.
Is it possible to have 2 routers on different sub nets issuing DCHP?

Comment: The answer is yes, but you need to give us more info here... The reality is you probably need a managed switch and to setup VLAN's or you need distinct cabling for each subnet. You can't just run multiple DHCP servers within the same broadcast domain, how would which router know if it should respond to a DHCP request or if it's not for them? VLANs is the answer, or distinct, separate networks.